# Error running the app after updating to Android Studio 3.4.1

Tags: android-studio-3.4

After updating to Android Studio 3.4.1, I was checking my app and came to understand that there is no error while debugging/building the app, but there is an error while running the app.

Ends up with an error something like below

```
error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/pivotX' with config ''.
error: resource previously defined here.

app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: error: file failed to compile.
```

Comment: Kindly help me out guys

Answer (score 0):

Guys I got the answer for the question...

Its in your .gradle file where you need to change the attribute name of the pivotX (attribute name shown in the error).

Location : C:\Users\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-2.0.0-beta1.aar\85a709bd4659f28dc59c0ee0faf968d5\res\values\values.xml

check for the line number in the error and in the same line check for the attribute name and change it to other name and save.

This solved my issue.